# Qt. Update the look of element before performing heavy function

Tags: qt

```
void MyClass::onButtonClicked(){
    QPushButton *button = static_cast<QPushButton*>(sender());
    button->setDisabled(true);
    performSomeHeavyFunctionFor5or10seconds();
}
```

I want my button to be visually updated before that function (now it's updated after). Should I use separate thread here? The second problem is that my program freezes while the function is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possibilities here:

1. Perform the heavy work in its own thread
2. Call [`QApplication::processEvents( QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents )`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) before you perform the heavy work in order to handle repaints etc. You can omit the flag by the way but I would leave it there so two fast clicks after one another can't cause random behaviour

Comment: thanks for #2. It has interesting feature) The button became disabled (gray text), but it remains pushed (its border)! I will think about it, but it seems to me, that separate thread is the solution for this.

Comment: if it remains pushed, try button->update() or repaint or something like that before calling processEvents()

Comment: It remains pushed as it's not getting user input event called "mouse  button release" ;). In this case setDisabled will ommit other input events on button

Comment: Is your onButtonClicked() slot connected to the pressed() or the clicked() signal? For the first case, would switching to clicked() be a problem? This is usually called after the button has been released.

Comment: Slot is connected to clicked() signal. Finally I decided to use threads - it is much more appropriate way in this case.